# On Isbell's "On coherent algebras and strict algebras"

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories, citations

In section 1.2 (p. 284) of his "Coherence theorems for lax algebras and for distributive laws," Kelly writes:

> It is a special case of the assertion of Isbell in [7], but this assertion has been withdrawn by its author; it asserts more than is true, and he discovered a radical error in the proof (at the Oberwolfach conference "Kategorien 1973").
>
> [7] J.R. Isbell, On coherent and strict algebras, *Jour. of Algebra* 13 (1969), 299-307.

My attempts to locate evidence corroborating Kelly's claim have so far been fruitless, although my acquaintance with the literature on 2-categories is only superficial, so I ask:

To which "radical error" does Kelly refer?

Comment: You may have already checked this, but Isbell's report from "Kategorien 1973" can be found at https://www.mfo.de/occasion/7330/www_view, as well as his abstract (look at 'image 20'). So if there's any discrepancy you may find it there, if indeed his talk ('Affine parts of algebraic theories') touched on what you are looking at.